# Нужна помощь в парсинге массива

Tags: c#, парсер, selenium, steam

Всем привет!

Мне необходимо спарсить цены за определенное количество дней данного предмета - https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Snakebite%20Case (снизу график, о нём идет речь).
Открыв код страницы, внизу я нашел длинный массив var line1, который как раз содержит в себе нужную мне информацию.

Для парсинга использую C# и Selenium, но, как правильно составить запрос для поиска данного var line1 - не представляю, т.к. здесь нет ни имени класса, ни тега, ни селектора и т.д.

Подскажите, как можно его спарсить ? Или, есть более простое решение моей задачи, может я чего-то проглядел ?

Comment: 1. Selenium != парсинг, Selenium == тестирование. Вы тестируете Steam сайт? Нет. Тогда для чего вам Selenium? 2. У Steam есть API, что мешает использовать его?  Вот вам [запрос](https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?&currency=5&appid=730&market_hash_name=Snakebite%20Case), выдаст цены в рублях (`currency=5`) в виде JSON. Единственное, нужна cookie `steamLogin`,  которую выдают после авторизации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Парсить это селениумом это как из гранатомета по воробьям. Есть способ проще. Решаю прямо в лоб не вникая в детали, вы просили способ выдрать данные из HTML - выдираю данные.

Так как нужная вам строка находится внутри яваскрипта, то HTML апрсер не поможет ее достать. Все что может здесь HTML парсер - это выдернуть `<script>` ноду и дать вам ее содержимое. Но ноду все равно придется разбирать как строку. Поэтому я сразу решил обработать весь HTML как строку.

Создаем контейнер для данных

```cs
class DataItem
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Date} {Value} {Id}";
    }
}
```

И пишем вот такой простой код

```cs
class Program
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Snakebite%20Case";
        string html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        string tmp = html.Substring(html.IndexOf("var line1=") + 10); // отпиливаем голову
        string json = tmp.Remove(tmp.IndexOf(";\r\n")); // отпиливаем хвост
        DataItem[] items = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement[][]>(json) // парсим этот кривой json
            .Select(o => new DataItem { Date = DateTime.Parse(o[0].GetString().Replace(":", ":00")), Value = o[1].GetDouble(), Id = o[2].GetString() }).ToArray();

        foreach (DataItem item in items) // выводим данные
            Console.WriteLine(item);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
04.05.2021 2:00:00 19,998 722
04.05.2021 3:00:00 15,107 2621
04.05.2021 4:00:00 14,391 2952
04.05.2021 5:00:00 13,61 2532
04.05.2021 6:00:00 12,19 2493
04.05.2021 7:00:00 13,43 2243
04.05.2021 8:00:00 13,438 1853
04.05.2021 9:00:00 13,799 1873
04.05.2021 10:00:00 13,08 2136
04.05.2021 11:00:00 10,758 2987
04.05.2021 12:00:00 10,611 3656
04.05.2021 13:00:00 9,282 3883
04.05.2021 14:00:00 9,156 4003
04.05.2021 15:00:00 8,576 4240
...
```

Comment: Большое спасибо)
Однако, не могу понять, почему не верно передаётся цена продаж ?
То, что мы передаём в double

Comment: @SPRVII как вы определили, что неверно, быть может валюта не та, которую вы ожидали? У меня вроде на баксы похоже.

Comment: @SPRVII если ответ был полезен, вы можете отметить его принятым, галочка слева от ответа.

Comment: и правда, я не учел валюту))
Привык, что у меня она в рублях